# PILKit was unable to import the Python Imaging Library

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am getting following error:

> raise ImportError('PILKit was unable to import the Python Imaging Library. Please confirm it's installed and available on your current Python path.')
>   ImportError: PILKit was unable to import the Python Imaging Library. Please confirm it's installed and available on your current Python path.

Comment: Have you confirmed that PIL is installed and available on your current Python path?

Comment: When I am trying to install 'pillow' using 'pip install pillow' its throwing following error:/fproject/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-s8dkkm/pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-UTclPh-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/manish/backup/mukul/fproject/include/site/python2.7/pillow" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-s8dkkm/pillow

Comment: Try downloading and pip-installing the wheel file from [gohlke's site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow).

Comment: I am using ubuntu this link seems to be for Windows.

Answer (score 9):

You have to install PIL or pillow, try:
`pip install pillow`